# Webpack ProvidePlugin/vendor bundle: angular.module is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have an Angular application that is currently built via Webpack into one large bundle, containing all dependencies and app code in a single file. I am trying to split the code into two bundles, one bundle with all of my dependencies, and another with all of my application code.

I have the following webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: `"${process.env.NODE_ENV}"`
    }
});

var SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/client');
var APP = path.resolve(SRC, 'app/index.js');
var DEST = path.resolve(__dirname, 'target/webapp/dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'angular',
            'angular-animate',
            'moment',
            'angular-moment',
            'angular-translate',
            'angular-ui-bootstrap',
            'angular-ui-router',
            'lodash'
        ],
        app: APP
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: 'lodash',
            angular: 'angular',
            angularMoment: 'angular-moment',
            angularTranslate: 'angular-translate',
            moment: 'moment',
            ngAnimate: 'angular-animate',
            uibootstrap: 'angular-ui-bootstrap',
            uirouter: 'angular-ui-router'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
        definePlugin
    ],
    output: {
        path: DEST,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        hash: true
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ['html'] },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css'] },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel?presets[]=es2015', 'eslint']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file'
            }
        ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')]
    }
};
```

This produces two bundles, one with only the dependencies and one with only the application code. However, when I attempt to load the application, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function` which is traced back to `angular-moment.js` within the `vendor.bundle.js`. In other words, `angular` isn't accessible to other modules that need to be loaded in the `vendor.bundle.js` file. However, I'm not sure how to make these dependencies visible to each other.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the headline of the original post, Angular 1 is not working nicely with webpack without a shim (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049). Try this webpack loader config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        /*
         * Necessary to be able to use angular 1 with webpack as explained in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2049
         */
        {
            test: require.resolve('angular'),
            loader: 'exports?window.angular'
        },
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'angular': 'angular',
    }),
],
```

This should initialize the angular object properly instead of the default action of setting it to an empty object (which does not have a property named module).

Answer (score 0):

Following should move all the scripts not in src folder to vendor chunk.

```
const path = require('path');
const projectRoot = path.resolve('./');

      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: (module) => module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(path.join(projectRoot, 'src')) === -1,
      }),
```